# Prove that $ x^4 - 2 $ is irreducible over $ \mathbb{Z}[i] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> How do I prove that $ p(x) = x^4 - 2 $ is irreducible over $ \mathbb{Z}[i] $?

This seems very elementary yet I'm not sure how to do it.

Someone suggested using Eisenstein and $ p = 1+i $, but this doesn't seem right because $ (1+i)^2 = 2i $ is an associate of $ -2 $.

I have seen somewhere that one can use a generalized version of the Rational Root Theorem and simply check that $ 1+i $ and $ 1-i $ are not roots of $ p(x) $, is this correct?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can, but you must also verify that it cannot be written as the product of two irreducible polynomials of degree $2$.

Comment: You are using the theorem that says that, if $R$ is a UFD, $p(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0\in R[x]$ (with $a_n\ne0$) and $\alpha\in\mathfrak{Frac}R$ is a root of $p$, then there are $s,t\in R$ such that $\alpha=\frac st$, $s\mid a_0$ and $t\mid a_n$. Which is a direct generalization of the rational root theorem. You are using it on the euclidean domain $\Bbb Z[i]$ in order to check for the root and prove that $p$ has no linear factors.

Comment: OK, understood. How do I verify that it cannot be written as the product of two irreducible polynomials of degree 2?

Comment: Then, it is in principle possible to write (you can always choose them monic because the product is monic) $$x^4-2=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$ and show that there are no solutions $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb Z[i]$.

Comment: Another way to do it: It is very easy to write down how this polynomial splits in its splitting field. Any product of two of these linear factors has a multiple of $\sqrt2$ as a coefficient, which does not lie in $\mathbb Z[i]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking roots is insufficient, as the equation had degree $4$ so it could potentially factored as 2 degree 2 polynomials.

Reduce the equation mod (3+2i). Then $\mathbb{Z}[i]\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_{13}$, $i\rightarrow 5$, and any integer get reduced mod 13=(3+2i)(3-2i). Then the equation is now $X^{4}-2$. If the equation was reducible before, it is still reducible now. But if it is reducible now, either it has a root, or it breaks as product of quadratic factors so either way all of its root lie in $\mathbb{F}_{169}$. Then $\mathbb{F}_{169}^{\times}$ is a cyclic group of order $168$, and $2$ has order $12$, so any roots must have order $48$ which is impossible as $48$ does not divide $168$.

EDIT: same calculation will also work for $\mathbb{F}_{5}$, as the other answer suggested.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I would prefer the following way which is also alluded in the comments:

$x^4-2=(x-\sqrt[4]{2}) (x+\sqrt[4]{2}) (x-i\sqrt[4]{2}) (x+i\sqrt[4]{2}) $ in $\mathbb{C}$.
Obviously  $\sqrt[4]{2}, -\sqrt[4]{2}, i\sqrt[4]{2}, -i\sqrt[4]{2}$ are not in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Since $\sqrt[4]{2}\cdot \sqrt[4]{2}=\sqrt{2}\notin \mathbb{Z}[i]$, there is no product of polynomials of degree two in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Answer (score 2):

You can also note that $x^4-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_5$ and $\mathbb F_5 = \mathbb Z[i]/(2+i)$.